# Charge Conjugation at Spinors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, spinors

In the schwartz book, Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model, at the chapter 11 is define the charge conjugation operator

$C:\;\;\psi\rightarrow-i\gamma^2\psi^*$

$C:\;\;\psi^*\rightarrow-i\gamma^2\psi$

and he start to use this operator at a lot of fields and combination of them, but the transformation of $\bar{\psi}\psi$ he use dirac index, but I want a different way who doesn't need to use them. I got this

$C:\;\;\bar{\psi}\psi\rightarrow(-i\gamma^2\psi)^T\gamma^0(-i\gamma^2\psi^*)=-\psi^T(\gamma^{2})^T\gamma^0\gamma^2\psi^*=-\psi^T\gamma^{2}\gamma^0\gamma^2\psi^*=-\psi^T\gamma^0\psi^*$

but I want

$C:\;\;\bar{\psi}\psi\rightarrow\bar{\psi}\psi$

so I need that $-\psi^T\gamma^0\psi^*=(\psi^T\gamma^0\psi^*)^T=\bar{\psi}\psi$

who ca I proof that without using Dirac index?